# How to reset the state returned from useFormState in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, react-dom, server-action

First of all here is my code in react

```
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from 'react-dom'
import { submitAction } from './action.ts'

export default function Calculator() {
  const [result, submitAction] = useFormState(submitForm, null)

  return (
   <>
    <form action={submitAction}>
      [input fields]

      <button type="reset">
        Reset
      </button>
      <CalculateButton />
    </form>

    <Table headers={inputsCols}>
        {result ? (
          Object.entries(result).map(([rowKey, rowData], rowIndex) => (
            <TableRow key={rowIndex}>
              <TableCell key={rowKey} className="font-bold">
                {rowKey}
              </TableCell>

              {Object.entries(rowData).map(([dataKey, dataValue]) => (
                <TableCell key={`${rowKey}-${dataKey}`}>{dataValue}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))
        ) : (
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell colSpan={inputsCols.length}>No data available</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        )}
      </Table>
    </>
  )
}

function CalculateButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus()

  return (
    <Button
      type="submit"
      color="orange"
      disabled={pending}
      icon={pending ? LoadingIcon : undefined}
    >
      Calculate
    </Button>
  )
}
```

I am trying to use reacts server action to submit a form and I want to reset

1. the form state and
2. the results returned from the server action

when user clicks the reset button.

the first thing working fine with using button type="reset" inside the form but for the second one I am not quite sure how should I do it.

So, **How can I reset the state returned from useFormState in react js?**
to update the UI so user can enter some other data and do other calculations.

Comment: I like to return a key from my server action, like `key: new Date.now()`, and then use a `useEffect` hook. Source: https://www.robinwieruch.de/next-forms/

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear there is a way to re-initialize the form state from *within* the component rendering the form. You *can*, however, use a React key to reset the form from outside.

See [Resetting a form with a key](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-a-form-with-a-key).

Use some state to represent a "form key" such that you can provide a new React key and effectively remount the `Calculator` component which will have the initial state.

```
export default function Calculator({ onReset }) {
  const [result, submitAction] = useFormState(submitForm, null)

  return (
   <>
    <form action={submitAction} onReset={onReset}>
      ...input fields...

      <button type="reset">
        Reset
      </button>
      <CalculateButton />
    </form>

    ...
    </>
  )
}
```

```
const [formKey, setFormKey] = React.useState(() => nanoid());

const updateFormKey = () => setFormKey(nanoid());
...

<Calculator key={formKey} onReset={updateFormKey} />
```

### Basic Demo

```js
const submitForm = (previousState, formData) => {
  console.log({ previousState });
  return previousState + 1;
};

function Calculator({ onReset }) {
  const [result, submitAction] = ReactDOM.useFormState(submitForm, 0);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form action={submitAction} onReset={onReset}>
        <div>Result: {result}</div>

        <button type="reset">
          Reset
        </button>
        <CalculateButton />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function CalculateButton() {
  const { pending } = ReactDOM.useFormStatus()

  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      disabled={pending}
    >
      Calculate ({pending ? "loading" : "idle" })
    </button>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [formKey, setFormKey] = React.useState(0);

  const updateFormKey = () => setFormKey(key => key + 1);
  return <Calculator key={formKey} onReset={updateFormKey} />;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.0-canary-cb2439624-20231219/umd/react.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-DyF9mlaay3VPTJNySTYIgb2dsv0NXOcY/IRkCFm/1J/w4B3oOXA6LGwS04cgMFHcSB5b7WXqbOsBaAsWsvcj8g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.0-canary-cb2439624-20231219/umd/react-dom.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-kkJ9iTzcc6cLoFeK+Kp13xvLpIa/+if1NSX7R1ThvHgw6VccDudy8qb5FGyismOvnaGfI604s7ZD6Rzu4Awpng==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For the time being, I think this is the solution I needed, but I think it is more of a hack than a solution (no offense). I think the React team is still developing it, and we'll get some solutions for it.

Comment: @AashutoshKumar No strong disagreement that this is a bit of a "hack", but it's one of the recommended methods of resetting a React component buried deep in the React docs. I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: @AashutoshKumar Actually, it seems React seems to have surfaced this use case a bit better in the newer docs: https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state and specifically [resetting a form with a key](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-a-form-with-a-key).

Comment: @AashutoshKumar Ok, found it. It was in an old React blog from 2018 regarding [derived state & anti-patterns](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key). Using the key to "reset" a component is one of the suggested preferred solutions.

Comment: I read the aforementioned blog, and that was helpful. I am using keys to reset the component state, and it is working fine, but there is an issue whenever the state of the form is reset because of changing the key.

Comment: The action value gets changed to `action="javascript:throw new Error('A React form was unexpectedly submitted. If you called form.submit() manually, consider using form.requestSubmit() instead. If you're trying to use event.stopPropagation() in a submit event handler, consider also calling event.preventDefault().')"`
But this does not affect the form submission and I do not get any errors in the console.

Comment: @AashutoshKumar Interesting, that's a new one to me. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the form code that reproduces that error/warning that we could inspect live?